# Catch EDT exceptions in a NetBeans environment

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, exception, event-dispatch-thread

I want to catch all uncaught exceptions and bring up a dialog. First I removed the default exception handler from NetBeans and added my handler as default handler:

```
java.util.logging.Logger global = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");
for (Handler handler : global.getHandlers()) {
  if (handler.getClass().getName().equals("org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging$LookupDel"))
  {
    global.removeHandler(handler);
    break;
  }
}
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
```

The handler looks like this:

```
public static final class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{

  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable)
  {
    logger.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
    ExceptionViewPanel.showException(throwable);
  }
}
```

With that construct, I can only catch exceptions which are thrown outside the EDT. I've read about ThreadGroups, but I can't use that solution due we use NetBeans with Maven and so I can't wrap the start thread with a ThreadGroup. The hack from pre-1.7 is also no longer possible and overwriting the EventQueue has no effect.

I've tried many solutions, none of them worked. Does anyone has another solution for me that might work?

Thanks in advance

Teazl

Answer (score 1):

In my own project I've superseded NetBeans error handler to my own. My example:

```
@ServiceProvider(service = Handler.class, supersedes = "org.netbeans.core.NbErrorManager")
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (record.getThrown() != null) {
            record.getThrown(); // do with it something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {

    }
}
```

See also org.netbeans.core.NbErrorManager and org.netbeans.core.NotifyExcPanel to know how NetBeans uses default handler.

You only need to add this class in your project.